# Using TypeGraphQL to generate typedefs and resolvers for Apollo local state in browser

Tags: typescript, webpack, typegraphql, apollo-link-state

I would like to use TypeGraphQL with Apollo local state in browser.

How can I use TypeGraphQL to generate typedefs and resolvers for Apollo local state in browser?

I saw the browser shim but the purpose seems to ignore TypeGraphQL decorators in shared files between client and server (e.g. entities/models).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking for examples on the TypeGraphQL repository?

https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/tree/master/examples/apollo-client